# PHP: way to get the true /tmp path?

Tags: php, centos7, systemd, temporary-files

I'm moving my web app from CentOS 5 to CentOS 7, and new security features regarding the /tmp directory are breaking my code. I'm wondering how best to handle it.

I have PHP code that creates a LaTeX file, then executes commands to turn that into a PDF, and then serves that to the user with appropriate headers. Here are some of the relevant lines of code as it stands now:

```
$fileroot = "/tmp/addr".getmypid();
ob_start();
/* echo all the LaTeX stuff */
file_put_contents($fileroot.".tex",ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
exec("cd /tmp;uplatex -interaction=batchmode --output-directory=/tmp $fileroot", $output, $return);
```

The settings in /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service include `PrivateTmp=true`, which causes `/tmp` within PHP function calls to really be `/tmp/systemd-private-6898f2d665d64b998981bc479ddc2306-php-fpm.service-KU8XML/tmp`. Yikes! That's fine for security, but exec() uses the `/tmp` path literally, so it can't find the file that `file_put_contents()` just created. The PHP function `sys_get_temp_dir()` just returns `/tmp`, and I can't find any environment variables with that path in them. Is there a way to get that path programmatically? Or do I need to turn off PrivateTmp? Or is there a better way to do what I need to do? Yes, I could create my own special spot with wide-open permissions, but it seems like it should be cleaner to just use the normal temporary directory.

Comment: What does `realpath("/tmp")` return?

Comment: When you use `sys_get_temp_dir()` it should get the path without you having to worry about hard coding it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php

Comment: When they say PHP has a function for everything they are not kidding.

Comment: As I said in my original question, `sys_get_temp_dir()` returns just "/tmp", not the real location. And `realpath("/tmp")` also returns "/tmp".

Comment: Do you really need to use the /tmp path? It's not secure, it has strong permissions rules attached and it's a routine system dependable.

I suggest create a /tmp path inside your project and manipulate freely at your will.

Comment: @Carlos: For my purposes it doesn't have to be secure. But I guess I'll need to use a custom directory - no one has mentioned anything I haven't thought of. It seems like a bug that `sys_get_temp_dir()` doesn't tell the truth, but it's not a problem as long as one only uses PHP functions, because they will all just use the same sandbox. It's the `exec()` that is getting me into trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, there are only two options:

1. Do not use `/tmp` but a different directory instead, which you predefine in your application's config file.  I have done something similar recently, where I used `/var/run/myapplication` directory instead of `/tmp`.  (I had to add a cron job to clean it up as well.)
2. Disable `PrivateTmp` in the php-frm service. Here's one way of doing this:

   ```
   # mkdir  /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d
   # echo -e "[Service]\nPrivateTmp=no" > /etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/privatetmp.conf
   # systemctl daemon-reload
   # systemctl restart php-fpm

   # systemctl show php-fpm | grep PrivateTmp
   PrivateTmp=no
   ```

Comment: Yeah, I guess those are the only options, unless someone else has an inspiration. I prefer option #1, as it keeps the system settings at their defaults. I already have a cron job to clean my stuff out of /tmp, so perhaps it's not a big deal to create my own special spot instead. It just seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: A small correction in your answer: I think it should be `PrivateTmp=false`, not `no`.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue. This is a way to find out the "real" temp path of a systemd service with PrivateTmp (in this case apache2):

```
 grep -oP ' /tmp/systemd-private-[^/]+-apache2[^/]+/tmp(?= /tmp)' /proc/`pgrep apache2 -o`/mountinfo
```

What it does:

- search for the process id of the oldest apache2 process: `pgrep apache2 -o`
- read the `/proc/PID/mountinfo` file, which contains the mount info as seen by this process
- extract the private tmp folder with a regular expression using `grep`

It may be that with future systemd versions or different settings, the regex needs to be adjusted, if the naming is different. You may also just use `' /tmp[^ ]+(?= /tmp)'` as the regex.

Note that it may not help you much to know the path. Private temp folders have strict permissions that only allow root access.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (on CentOS) and fixt it with the following steps.

```
nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
```

Look in to the file and
`PrivateTmp=false` to `PrivateTmp=true`

```
systemctl daemon-reload
service http restart
```

And you are ready2go

Comment: You didn't read my question carefully. Mine is already set to `true`, and that is what is causing my dilemma. Yes, I could set it to `false`, but `true` is better for security. Plus, the setting that would affect my code is for php-fpm, not httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Aleks G is the correct way, but if you still in trouble try this.

I've try "multi-user.target.wants" solution, it have worked but after restart, but at some point, PrivateTmp go back to true.
Like my principal use of Apache2 is PHP, I finally edited php.ini and I've uncomment line sys_temp_dir.

By default system use temp dir assigned by function sys_get_temp_dir. Function sys_get_temp_dir will return "/tmp" but the truth is that your tmp files are storing at some path like /tmp/systemd-private-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-apache2.service-YYYYYY//tmp/*. So, what work for me was:

Edit php.ini (path can change between PHP versions)

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Then uncomment sys_temp_dir line

```
; Directory where the temporary files should be placed.
; Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir)
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```